# How to publish the Places map from Aperture with geotagged pictures?

Tags: photos, sharing, aperture, geolocation, maps

So I have a set of pictures taken along the way of a road trip. They were taken with an iPhone so they're geotagged but we could be dealing with manually geotagged pics, doesn't matter. I want to publish the equivalent of what I see in the Places section of Aperture. A map (any provider is fine) fully scrollable and or zoomable, with my set of pictures on it. Pics could be thumbnails or pins until you click on it, it doesn't matter.

Is my only solution the iPad iPhoto app and its journal feature? (never used it so I'm just guessing) Would that do the trick? Any other Mac software out there (dare I dream of an Aperture plugin?) that could do that?

Answer (score 1):

One solution that I used before is to publish it on Flickr and use their map feature. I think I can directly share the link to the map with my friends. One needs to make sure to include geolocation data when uploading.

As an aside, not crazy about Flickr anymore, my subscription is about to expire and I would like to find something else, hence the question !

EDIT: A better solution seems to be picasa, with an upload to picasa web and options to get a google map online or a Google Earth kml file.